# Storing Tenant Id in Multi-tenancy ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, multi-tenant

I am working on a ASP.Net MVC3 multitenancy application with **Shared DB** approach. I mean a single database that shares all the tenant information with the identifier TenantId in each table.

```
URL will never change 
URL will not look like tenant1.app.com or app.com/tenant1.
The reason is not to show any tenant information on URL for secure access.
```

Based on the user name and password we authenticate in the database and get the tenant id for him. My Application User table has a field called tenant id. After Form Authentication i need to maintain this Tenant ID for each subsequent request.

**Now the question here is where i keep Tenant Id safe? Session or Cookie and use Global Action Attribute to get the Tenant Context?**

Any code snippet and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It would be nice to know how do you solved it.